# How to save Word document in specified folder with filedialog.saveas?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I used the MO 14.0 Object library.

I want to open the filedialog.saveas where the user can choose the folder to save a Word document. Then open the document and write data from an Access database.

I found how to open, to fill in the data and how to open the filedialog.

The problem is that the chosen datafile is not saved at the location where it should be.

```vb
Private Sub Befehl44_Click()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With objWord
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open (CurrentProject.Path & "\template.docx") 'template for word document
        .activedocument.Bookmarks("email").Select 
        .Selection.Text = Me!email 
        .activedocument.Bookmarks("name").Select
        .Selection.Text = Me!name
        .Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does strPath return the correct filepath the user selected for saving?

If it does, you just need to call the SaveAs method directly from Word

**After**

`strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)`

**Insert Lines**
`If strPath <> "" Then 
    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPath
End If`

**Or - just replace it with one line**

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you! The first one was fine but instead of .activeworkbook it needs to write .activedocument.saveas strpath...